# Procedure with Implicit cursor is compiling but not printing

Tags: loops, plsql, cursor

i am currently stuck on this pl/sql problem, i am trying to gather all the information of a APPLICANT who APPLIES to a certain POSITION (3 different tables) into a stored procedure.

Unfortunately i am very new to oracle and pl/sql so i think my joins may be sloppy aswell as my main problem of dbms_output.put_line is not printing out the data that i need. I figure maybe it is in the wrong place in the code block or there is a problem coming all the way down from my join statements.

```
enter code here 
SET ECHO ON
SET FEEDBACK ON
SET LINESIZE 100
SET PAGESIZE 100
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APPLICANTS IS
first_name APPLICANT.FNAME%TYPE;
last_name APPLICANT.LNAME%TYPE;
position_number APPLIES.PNUMBER%TYPE;
position_title POSITION.TITLE%TYPE;
str VARCHAR(300);

CURSOR fnameCursor IS
SELECT FNAME
FROM APPLICANT;  

BEGIN
FOR fnameCursor IN (SELECT APPLICANT.LNAME, APPLIES.PNUMBER, 
POSITION.TITLE INTO last_name, position_number, position_title
                    FROM APPLICANT JOIN APPLIES ON APPLICANT.ANUMBER = 
APPLIES.ANUMBER
                    JOIN POSITION ON POSITION.PNUMBER = APPLIES.PNUMBER
                    WHERE FNAME = first_name
                    ORDER BY LNAME DESC)
LOOP

str := position_number || '' || first_name || '' || last_name || ': ' || 
position_title;
dbms_output.put_line(str);

--EXIT WHEN fnameCursor%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;

END APPLICANTS;
/

EXECUTE APPLICANTS;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is surprising to know that the procedure is compiling. You are using an `INTO` clause inside an implicit cursor query. Also, I believe `first_name` should come as an argument to your procedure but you have not mentioned it.
More importantly, the columns selected/aliased within the cursor should be referred within the loop using cursor's record variable `fnamecursor`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APPLICANTS(first_name APPLICANT.FNAME%TYPE)
IS
  str VARCHAR(300);
BEGIN
     FOR fnamecursor IN (
          SELECT applicant.lname as last_name,
                 applies.pnumber as position_number,
                 position.title  as position_title
          FROM applicant
          JOIN applies  ON applicant.anumber = applies.anumber
          JOIN position ON position.pnumber = applies.pnumber
          WHERE fname = first_name
          ORDER BY lname DESC
     ) LOOP
          str := fnamecursor.position_number || ' '   || first_name || ' ' || 
                       fnamecursor.last_name || ': ' || fnamecursor.position_title;
          dbms_output.put_line(str);

     END LOOP;
END applicants;
/
```